# Duplicate button on iOS keyboard toolbar potentially due to foreach loop positioning

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm currently working on a project and struggling with duplicate buttons appearing within the toolbar upon keyboard pop-up.

Essentially if I have 3 warm-ups in my list I'll have 3 dismiss keyboard buttons. I think it's due to the ForEach loop but I'm not 100% sure on this one. Code is below

```
import SwiftUI

    struct WarmUpSection: View {
    @Binding var warmUp: [WarmUp]
    @FocusState private var focusedField: Int?

    var body: some View {
        Section(header: Text("Warm-up")) {
            ForEach(warmUp.indices, id: \.self) { warmUpIndex in
                HStack {
                    TextField("New warm-up", text: Binding(
                        get: { warmUp[warmUpIndex].description },
                        set: { newValue in
                            warmUp[warmUpIndex].description = newValue
                        }
                    ))
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: warmUpIndex)
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard) {
                            Spacer()
                            Button(action: {
                                focusedField = nil
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "keyboard.chevron.compact.down")
                                    .font(.system(size: 20))
                                    .foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.black))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onDelete(perform: deleteWarmUp)
                        
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                Text("Add Warmup")
                    .foregroundColor(.blue)
                Spacer()
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                let newIndex = warmUp.count
                warmUp.append(WarmUp(description: ""))
                focusedField = newIndex
            }
        }
    }

    func deleteWarmUp(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        warmUp.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
    }
```

Screenshot can be found here - [Duplicate Buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ0WU.png)

Comment: try moving the `.toolbar` outside the `ForEach` loop.

Comment: Weirdly it worked while still inside the loop just further down in the code. I don't know why but it did.

I moved it to just above
````  
} 
func deleteWarmUp(at offsets: etc. 

````